# Html hyperlink body option in mailto does not support some special characters like '&'

Tags: hyperlink, outlook, special-characters, mailto

I'm using hyperlinks to provide a mailto feature, I'm dynamically creating body for the email,
Code for body

```
let value = 50;
let titlevar = stack overflow example
let myLink = "http://localhost:5500/abc/def.html?did=" + value + "&title=" + titlevar
let emailstring = `mailto:?Subject=Sometext&body=Click here to view my example:  %0D ` + myLink
```

I'm using a tag as,

```
<a href="` + emailstring + `">
```

but while opening this link, In outlook the string is breaking. I only get this,
http://localhost:5500/abc/def.html?did=50

I think outlook is restricting `'&'` this symbol so I have tried with replacing it with comma(`','`), it was working as expected

And I'm having spaces in `titlevar` so i have tried `encodeURI(titlevar)` this returns `stack%20overflow%20example`. This is also not supporting in outlook. It is breaking at http://localhost:5500/abc/def.html?did=50,title=stack.

It is not working in outlook, I didn't try with gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the entire url value after `Subject=` with `encodeURIComponent`.

If the subject contains HTML and/or urls themselves, then those also need to be encoded using encodeURI. Yes, this means 2 layers of encodeURIComponent for some parts.

```
const myLink = "http://localhost:5500/abc/def.html?did=" + value + "&title=" + encodeURIComponent(titlevar);
const body = encodeURIComponent('Click here to view my example: ' + myLink);
const emailstring = `mailto:?Subject=Sometext&body=${body}`;
```

The general issue is that you should always encode your strings when you are embedding them in a url. If that encoded string is embedded in *another* url, encode that too.